# Spark hive udf: no handler for UDAF analysis exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, spark-hive

Created one project 'spark-udf' & written hive udf as below:

```
package com.spark.udf
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF

class UpperCase extends UDF with Serializable {
  def evaluate(input: String): String = {
    input.toUpperCase
  }
```

Built it & created jar for it. Tried to use this udf in another spark program:

```
spark.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uppercase AS 'com.spark.udf.UpperCase' USING JAR '/home/swapnil/spark-udf/target/spark-udf-1.0.jar'")
```

But following line is giving me exception:

```
spark.sql("select uppercase(Car) as NAME from cars").show
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No
>   handler for UDAF 'com.spark.udf.UpperCase'. Use
>   sparkSession.udf.register(...) instead.; line 1 pos 7     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.makeFunctionExpression(SessionCatalog.scala:1105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$catalog$SessionCatalog$$makeFunctionBuilder$1.apply(SessionCatalog.scala:1085)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$catalog$SessionCatalog$$makeFunctionBuilder$1.apply(SessionCatalog.scala:1085)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry.lookupFunction(FunctionRegistry.scala:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.lookupFunction(SessionCatalog.scala:1247)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$applyOrElse$52.apply(Analyzer.scala:1226)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$applyOrElse$52.apply(Analyzer.scala:1226)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$.withPosition(package.scala:48)

Any help around this is really appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to write a hive-UDF to use in Spark? Better define a spark UDF if you want to use it in spark

Comment: I have also tried spark UDF but got same exception:

import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1
class UpperCase extends UDF1[String, String] with Serializable {
  override def call(t1: String): String = t1.toUpperCase
}

Comment: How are you adding the UDF jar to your Spark program ?

Comment: @philantrovert I am adding jar is same command "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION"
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uppercase AS 'com.spark.udf.UpperCase' USING JAR '/home/swapnil/spark-udf/target/spark-udf-1.0.jar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it's better to write Spark UDF:

```
val uppercaseUDF = spark.udf.register("uppercase", (s : String) => s.toUpperCase)
spark.sql("select uppercase(Car) as NAME from cars").show
```

Main cause is that you didn't set `enableHiveSupport` during creation of SparkSession. In such situation, default SessionCatalog will be used and `makeFunctionExpression` function in `SessionCatalog` scans only for User Defined Aggregate Function. If function is not an UDAF, it won't be found.

Created [Jira task](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25334) to implement this

Comment: @SwapnilChougule Changed slightly my answer, please check it - should work :)

Comment: @Gaweda I had enabled Hive support also. With hive support, hive udf works.
I want to use scala UDF through external jar. Even I observed makeFunctionExpression only supports UDAF but not UDF. This is what I was seeking. You have opened JIRA for this :)

Comment: Thanks enabling hive was what I was lacking of.

Comment: Hello Sir @Gaweda, I'd like to use `spark.udf.register()` to add UDF from JAR files. Could you please give me some pointers/references?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is class needs to be public.

```
package com.spark.udf
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF

public class UpperCase extends UDF with Serializable {
  def evaluate(input: String): String = {
    input.toUpperCase
  }
}
```

Comment: Issue was with spark 2.3.0. Please test with it. There was no handler as mentioned above. Don't know about recent versions. You can also check corresponding jira